# Getting Docker image and Docker-Compose file to work correctly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file and docker compose fiel in my project directory. I am running the docker compose file with the following command

`docker-compose up`

It builds and runs the different images for the server and database, but I am getting an error that is saying my package.json file is not in the correct directory. I am not sure where it is going wrong.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 5585
```

this is my docker compose file

```
web:
  image: node
  command: npm start
  ports:
    - "5585:5588"
  links:
    - db
  working_dir: /app
  environment:
    SEQ_DB: addidas
    SEQ_USER: sdfsdf
    SEQ_PW: sdfsdfs
    PORT: 4242
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://sdfsdf:sdfsdfs@localhost:5432/addidas
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: sdfsdf
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sdfsdfs
```

the error that i am getting in my terminal is the following :

```
Attaching to addidas_db_1, addidas_web_1
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   | 
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   | 
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   | 
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   | 
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   | 
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2018-11-06 17:38:51.968 UTC [43] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:51.983 UTC [44] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-11-06 17:38:51 UTC
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:51.987 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | CREATE DATABASE
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1   | 
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down...2018-11-06 17:38:52.438 UTC [43] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | .2018-11-06 17:38:52.441 UTC [43] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.443 UTC [43] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 50) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.444 UTC [45] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.459 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.556 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.556 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.560 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.575 UTC [61] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-11-06 17:38:52 UTC
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:38:52.580 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:15.922 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:15.926 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 67) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:15.928 UTC [62] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:15.944 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:19.284 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:19.284 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:19.288 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:19.309 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-11-06 17:46:15 UTC
db_1   | 2018-11-06 17:46:19.316 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
web_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
web_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent 
web_1  | 
web_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
web_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-11-06T17_47_14_825Z-debug.log
addidas_web_1 exited with code 254
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using your docker image your docker-compose.yml.

You should point to your Dockerfile:

```
web:
  build: ./path/to/Dockerfile
```

There is also some mistakes with your configuration. You should share the containers (your web server and the database) on the same network to be able to access the database from the web server.

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

web:
  build: ./path/to/Dockerfile
  networks:
    - mynetwork
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    SEQ_DB: addidas
    SEQ_USER: sdfsdf
    SEQ_PW: sdfsdfs
    PORT: 4242
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://sdfsdf:sdfsdfs@db:5432/addidas

db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    - mynetwork
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: sdfsdf
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sdfsdfs
```